# When to use "en" vs. "de" after the verb "depender"

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I have come across examples online that use ***depender de*** as well as examples that use ***depender en***.

Are both examples below gramatically correct?  And if so, when is it ***depender de*** and when is it ***depender en***?

Examples of ***depender de:***

1. depender de algo
2. todo depende de lo que decida el juez
3. depender de alguien
4. depende de ti

Examples of ***depender en:***

1. Por tanto, estamos empezando a preocuparnos, una vez más, por depender en mayor medida de Rusia en el futuro.
2. ¿Va a depender en algún momento su adhesión del veto de alguno de los países que ahora son candidatos?
3. Además , será preciso depender en gran medida de las operaciones aéreas de abastecimiento.

Answer (score 16):

***Depender en*** is not a grammatical phrase. *Depender* goes with *de*. What you have found are instances of *depender de* in which other phrases come in between *depender* and *de*. This is perfectly correct and very common. *Depender de* is not an inseparable fixed phrase.

In all your examples with *depender en*, the preposition *en* is part of a complement that you could in principle delete...

> *Por tanto, estamos empezando a preocuparnos, una vez más, por **depender** <s>en mayor medida</s> **de** Rusia en el futuro.*

or move:

> *Por tanto, estamos empezando a preocuparnos, una vez más, por **depender de** Rusia en mayor medida en el futuro.*

In this other example not one but two things come between *depender* and *de* (marked with [square brackets]): a complement of time (*en algún momento*) and the subject (*su adhesión*):

> *¿Va a depender [en algún momento] [su adhesión] del veto de alguno de los países que ahora son candidatos?*

As above, you could move things around so that *depender* is followed immediately by *de(l)*:

> *¿Su decisión va en algún momento a **depender de**l veto de alguno de los países que ahora son candidatos?*

As you see, Spanish allows for a lot of movement within the sentence.

Why do these things come in between the verb *depender* and its dependent phrase headed by *de*? Well, because they can, and because it sounds better or more natural sometimes. You could have something like

> *Dependemos para lograr este objetivo, a causa de la situación actual, en gran medida y por un plazo de tiempo indefinido, de...*

where the verb and *de* are separated by several long complements.